# Java: find exact path of each property within a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hi I wrote a JSON tree parser in Java using Jackson. Now I want to find the path of each property within the JSON. Example JSON:

```
{"product":{
    "name":"Flipper",
    "industry":"Real Estate",
    "description":"Discovers correlations and trending criteria.",
    "someArray": ["bla1", "bla2", "bla3"],
    "productspecs":{"spec1":"somespec1",
                      "spec2":"someotherspec2"},
    "arrayOfObjects":[{"test1": "a1", "test2":"a2"},
                        {"Hi1": "b1", "Hi2":"b2"}]
},
"name":"Peter",
"anotherArray":["la1", "la2"]}
```

An example of a path within this JSON is:

```
/product/industry
```

which would have as value

```
"Real Estate"
```

The parser I wrote gets all the properties that directly contain a value (not another JSON object). Here's the code:

```
public void processJson(String jsonStr) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr);  
        first = true;
        processNode(node);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void processNode(JsonNode n) {  
    if (n.isContainerNode()) {
        if (n.isArray()){
            Iterator<JsonNode> itt = n.iterator();
            while (itt.hasNext()) {
                JsonNode innerNode = itt.next();
                processNode(innerNode);
            }
        }
        else {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = n.fields();
            Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field;               
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()){
                field = fieldsIterator.next();
                this.lastKey = field.getKey();      
                location += "/" + this.lastKey;
                processNode(field.getValue());
            }
        }       
    }
    else if (n.isNull()) {
        propertyCount++;
        System.out.println("Key: " + this.lastKey + " Value: " + n);
    } else {
        propertyCount++;
        location = location.substring(0,location.lastIndexOf("/"));

        System.out.println("Key: " + this.lastKey  + " Value: " + n.asText());          
    }
}
```

The code can be run like:

```
processJson(ExampleJSON);
```

And gives as a result:

```
Key: name Value: Flipper
Key: industry Value: Real Estate
Key: description Value: Discovers correlations and trending criteria.
Key: someArray Value: bla1
Key: someArray Value: bla2
Key: someArray Value: bla3
Key: spec1 Value: somespec1
Key: spec2 Value: someotherspec2
Key: test1 Value: a1
Key: test2 Value: a2
Key: Hi1 Value: b1
Key: Hi2 Value: b2
Key: name Value: Peter
Key: anotherArray Value: la1
Key: anotherArray Value: la2
```

Now for each of these I would like to get the path within the JSON. So:

```
Key: name Value: Flipper Path: product/name
Key: industry Value: Real Estate Path: product/industry
Key: description Value: Discovers correlations and trending criteria. Path: product/description
Key: someArray Value: bla1 Path: product/someArray
Key: someArray Value: bla2 Path: product/someArray
Key: someArray Value: bla3 Path: product/someArray
```

And so on....

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you define &  initialized variables - first, location, and propertyCount in your code? tx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would do it is to add another parameter to your recursive method processNode, that would represent the current path.

```
private void processNode(JsonNode n, String currentPath)
```

And every time you go deeper in recursion, call the method with the currentPath appended with the key you are going into.

```
while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
    field = fieldsIterator.next();
    this.lastKey = field.getKey();
    location += "/" + this.lastKey;
    processNode(field.getValue(), currentPath + "/" + this.lastKey);
}
```

So in the print part you would have:

```
propertyCount++;
location = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/"));

System.out.println("Key: " + this.lastKey + " Value: " + n.asText() + " Path: " + currentPath);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you define &  initialized variables - first, location, and propertyCount in your code?

Comment: location must be also below: 
location = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf("/"));

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the key, value, path for emptyNode, for example

```
{"emptyNode": {}}
```

then add

```
 else if(n.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Key: " + this.lastKey + " Value: " + n.asText() + " Path: " + path);
        }
```